# What is the best way to set defaults values of a Symfony object?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I'm actually learning Symfony3, while I was setting default values of the fields of an object and I discovered that I couldn't set a DateTime object as a default value on the common way I learned from the tutorial I was following (cf. the following code).

```
<?php    
namespace UTM\UsersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utm_users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uuid", columns={"uuid"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username", columns={"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="group_id", columns={"group_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{

    //...

    private $var = 'value';

    //...

}
```

So I looked for a solution and I found out that I can use constructor to make this possible so I've done the following code.

```
<?php    
namespace UTM\UsersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utm_users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uuid", columns={"uuid"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username", columns={"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="group_id", columns={"group_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{

    //...

    private $var;

    //...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setVar(new DateTime('0000-00-01 00:00:00'));
    }

    //...

}
```

But now I'm wondering what is the best way to set default values of an object. Is it better to use only the __construct function or a mix of these 2 methods is the best approach.

Thank you for reading and I hope someone will provide me an answer to this question.

Comment: Using the `__constructor` allows for more. As you observed, assigning objects, or constants, depending on your PHP version is problematic. Also using ctor permits you to override a 'default' at instantiation. This might be worth a read (prototype pattern): http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you setting default values for a properties if it is possible. If not, use the constructor. Keep in mind that in doctrine ORM constructor can be omitted in some cases.
Also, don't forget to set annotation for a column declaration

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class City {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Column(type="string", length="50", options={"default" : "Washington DC"})
     */
    private $name = 'Washington DC';
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't forget annotations I have removed them in order to make the topic smoother.

Answer (score 2):

I would say better to define default values in `__construct`, as you will see all of them in one place(especially when you have many properties) and you can assign objects, not only scalar values.

```
namespace UTM\UsersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class User
{

    //...

    private $created;


    private $enabled;

    //...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->enabled = true;
    }

    //...

}
```